# Canonical isomorphism between (product/sum of) module homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

In my lecture slides there is the following proposition.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M_i$ and $N$ be $R$-modules, then there exists a canonical $R$-isomorphism

\begin{equation}
\text{Hom}_R(\bigoplus_{i\in I} M_i,N)\cong_R \prod_{i\in I}\text{Hom}_R(M_i,N),\\
\text{Hom}_R(N,\prod_{i\in I} M_i)\cong_R \prod_{i\in I}\text{Hom}_R(N,M_i).
\end{equation}
I have two questions (which might be related). The first one is how would one be able to prove this, I see why it should be true, but I can't come up with an isomorphism that works, I've also tried using the isomorphism theorem but without any success.
The second is, why is it that in the first isomorphism there is a direct sum and not a direct product like in the second isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it the second equation follows in general for products from their universal property, specifically:

Take $\pi_{i}:\prod{M_i}\to M_i$ to be the projection into the n-th coordinate. Now you get an isomorphism between a map $\phi :N\to \prod{M_i}$ to its coordinate function by applying $\pi_{i}$. Conversely every $\phi$ is completely determined by those coordinate functions.

For the first one we do it similarly:

Take $\psi_i:M_i \to N$ the restriction of $\psi \in Hom_R(\bigoplus{M_i},N)$ to each $M_i$ and now take the map $\psi \mapsto \prod{\psi_i}$. For the inverse take $\prod{\psi_i'} \mapsto \psi'$ where we define by how it works on each $M_i$. This clearly works out as a bijection we just have to check out that it is well defined as a homomorphism of modules:

The one direction from left to right should be clear as restriction is compatible with R-linear combinations.

For the other one take $\psi_1 = \prod{\psi_{1_i}} ,\psi_2 = \prod{\psi_{2_i}} \in \prod{Hom_R(M_i,N)}$, $m = m_{i_1} +...+m_{i_n} \in \bigoplus{M_i}$ s.t. $m_{i_j} \in M_{i_j}$ and $a \in R$

Now by construction: $(a*\psi_1+\psi_2)(m)$
$ = (a*\psi_1+\psi_2)_{i_1}(m_{i_1})+...+(a*\psi_1+\psi_2)_{i_n}(m_{i_n})$ $ = a*(\psi_1)_{i_1}(m_{i_1})+(\psi_2)_{i_1}(m_{i_1})+...+a*(\psi_1)_{i_n}(m_{i_n})+(\psi_2)_{i_n}(m_{i_n})$ $= a *\psi_1(m)+\psi_2(m)$

These computations show that the map from right to left is R-linear and we therefor have an isomorphism. The reason this works out is that although we have a lot of homomorphisms on the rigth al but finitely many are zero on elements in the direct sum, because ring-homomorphisms map zero to zero, so we still work with finite sums.

The abstract reason why we once have the product and once the direct sum on one side, but the product on both sides, is that $Hom_R(N,-)$ is a covariant functor, $Hom_R(-,N)$ is a contravariant functor and that R-Modules are an abelian category, so coproducts turn to products, if you take the opposite category. This explanation heavily relies on knowledge of category theory.

Therefor another explanation might be that although in the direct sum you only have finitely many coordinates that are non-zero a map from there still has to be defined for all coordinates seperately and as seen above is still well defined for all combinations. This probably isn't completely accurate and a bit handwavy so if someone else has a better concrete explanation, please post it as well.